# file upload python script with graph api gives error 400

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

i want to send a request with the upload_url i have but the code keeps giving me header errors i think the headers of my put request isnt goof

```
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token'],
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
    upload_url = response.json()["uploadUrl"]

    CHUNK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024  # 4MB
with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        if not chunk:
            break
        print(f"bytes {f.tell() - len(chunk)}-{f.tell() - 1}/{f.seek(0, 2)}")
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
            "Content-Length": str(len(chunk)),
            "Content-Range": f"bytes {f.tell() - len(chunk)}-{f.tell() - 1}/{f.seek(0, 2)}"
        }
    response  = requests.put(upload_url, headers=headers, data=chunk)
    print(headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        print("File uploaded successfully")
    else:
        print(
            f"Upload failed with status code {response.status_code}")
```

```
headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
            "Content-Length": str(len(chunk)),
            "Content-Range": f"bytes {f.tell() - len(chunk)}-{f.tell() - 1}/{f.seek(0, 2)}"
        }
    response  = requests.put(upload_url, headers=headers, data=chunk)
```

output:
`{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"The Content-Range header is missing or malformed."}}`

expected:

```
response.status_code == 201:
        print("File uploaded successfully")
```

Answer (score 0):

add `content-type` in your header that youre using to make the upload api request.

```
headers = {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + result['access_token'],
            "Content-Type": 'application/octet-stream'
        }
```